# MVC 4 - pass parameter to controller from URL while collecting form data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller, asp.net-mvc-4, http-post, parameter-passing

I have a form on my view with 2 fields. The user clicks on the submit button and some data will be queried specific to that user and the data they entered into the form.
The user's email address is passed on the URL. (e.g. ActionName?user_email=yaddd@yyy.com)
I need to collect the form data and the email from the URL and pass it into my controller.

I need the data to query from my database and display a message to the user.

I can't find any good links or sites regarding this issue.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Collect(String s1, String s2, string user_email)
    {}
    and 
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Collect(FormCollection fm, string user_email)
    {}
```

They don't seem to collect the form data at all. What do you suggest?

Comment: _Don't seem to collect it_? Have you tried debugging your code and seeing what is passed into the user_email variable? Does it have a value or not?

Can you see the user email on the URL that is generated in your browser?

Comment: Yes, I can see the email on the URL.

Comment: I did try to debug and see if a value was collected from the form but nothing showed up at all :(

Comment: Nothing at all? so your code stopped at the debug point (verifying that it is indeed calling the correct controller), and you saw the variable in the debug and it was empty?

Comment: What does your form element look like?  What do your inputs look like?

Comment: My inputs are 2 password-type input boxes. There was a nullreference exception when i tried to get the values out of the form collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using model binding? Ideally, I would use model binding for the data you are sending in the form and use parameters on action for the querystrings. So in your case I would define a model like below

```
public class MyModel
{
    public string S1 {get; set;}
    public string S1 {get; set;}
}
```

And then define the action as

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Collect(MyModel model, string user_email)
{
}
```

This has always worked for me. Give it a try and let me know if it does not work

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I thought it was strange that just the formcollection did not work in this case!

Answer (score 1):

Are you handling the request in the same controller? Just wondering if you are routing to the correct controller.

Otherwise you could try using:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Collect( /* Your input parameters */ )
{
   string email = Request.QueryString["user_email"];
   // Code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This one finally worked!

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Collect(MyModel model)
{

string email = Request.QueryString["user_email"];
// Code

}
```